# How to retrieve data immediately from database followed by insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**I am inserting data into a table using the following query. Now, how can I able to retrieve that inserted data. I have tried in this way but it is not working. Help with this.**

event_id is the field which is present in the events table and is auto incremented.

```
$sql=$con->query("INSERT INTO events 
   (gname,location,date_from,date_to,venue_details,email,participants)VALUES ('$gname','$location','$date_from','$date_to','$venue_details','$email','$participants');");
        $immediate = $con->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE gname==$gname AND location==$location AND date_from==$date_from AND date_to==$date_to AND venue_details==$venue_details AND email==$email AND participants==$participants;");
        $retrieve = mysqli_fetch_array($immediate);
        $selfid = $retrieve['event_id'];
        $insert = $con->query("INSERT INTO usersregisteredevents (event_id, email) VALUES ($selfid,$email);");'
```

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve data you already have? Also, SQL uses `=` not `==` and strings need quoted.

Comment: `==` __does not__ work in mysql.

Comment: @JonStirling to insert into another table once event_id is created !!

Comment: So you just need ID od last added row.

Comment: You should probably get the *last insert id* if you're using auto-increment ids…!?

Comment: @RussJ - They need the `insert_id`

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by getting last inserted ID

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tmp` (`name`, `data`) VALUES ('somename','somedata');";
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $insertId = $con->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $insertId;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

//Optional if you want this row
$immediate = $con->query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id = $insertId");
$retrieve = mysqli_fetch_array($immediate);

//or you can do another query using just $insertId
$insert = $con->query("INSERT INTO usersregisteredevents (event_id, email) VALUES ($insertId, 'someemail';");
```

With this ID you can ask DB to get this new row, or just use ID to be used in other table.

Comment: Code still doesn't work. And no one asked for last_insert_id

Comment: @Volvox getting an error like trying to get property 'event_id' of non-object

Comment: @Vive Well, not from this particular code…

Comment: Anybody help !!

Comment: @Vive *How?!* This code does not produce *that* error. What code produces that error for you we don't know. And you haven't responded once to the entire suggestion of auto-increment ids…

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I've updated example